# how convert XML to List<Map>

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a XML data like below given Example..

```
<EMP>
   <PERSONAL_DATA>
     <EMPLID>AA0001</EMPLID>
     <NAME>Adams<NAME>
   </PERSONAL_DATA>
   <PERSONAL_DATA>
     <EMPLID>AA0002<EMPLID>
     <NAME>Paul<NAME>
    </PERSONAL_DATA>
</EMP>
```

I want to store information about each employee in a Map(KEY,VALUE) KEY=tagname, VALUE=value and want to create a LIST for all employee using XPATH in java. how i Do?
Please suggest 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract XML Information to List<Map> using XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296126/extract-xml-information-to-listmap-using-xpath)

Comment: @Sandeep - Voted to close, because this is an exact dup of a question you asked yesterday. However, I provided an answer on that other question. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296126/extract-xml-information-to-listmap-using-xpath/8316642#8316642

Answer (score 3):

You can use JAXB.

I can see at least 2 solution. First is: create class `PersonalData` with fields `emplid` and `name`. Mark them with `@XmlElement` annotations. Parse your XML. This will create collection of instances of `PersonalData`. Now iterate over this collection and create map if you really need it.

But you can map XML to map directly. Take a look on the following [blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the normal [jaxp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxp/index.html) stuff or try groovy:

```
String xml='''<EMP>
   <PERSONAL_DATA>
     <EMPLID>AA0001</EMPLID>
     <NAME>Adams</NAME>
   </PERSONAL_DATA>
   <PERSONAL_DATA>
     <EMPLID>AA0002</EMPLID>
     <NAME>Paul</NAME>
    </PERSONAL_DATA>
</EMP>
'''
Node parsed=new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
List<Map> list=[]
parsed.each {
    Map<String,String> map=[:]
    it.children().each {
        map[it.name()]=it.value()[0]
        println "${it.name()} ${it.value()[0]}"
    }
    list.add(map)
}
println list
```

Comment: my complete question is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296126/extract-xml-information-to-listmap-using-xpath   pls have a look if possible

Comment: there is http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html - their sample works fine. i am not familiar with xpath - i tried fooling around with this using your xml, but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the XPATH?                                                                              `String expression = "//EMP/PERSONAL_DATA/*";
         XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression);

```
     Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
     NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;  

     List<Map> list = new ArrayList<Map>();

     for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {  
           Node node = nodes.item(i);
           Map<String,String> nodeMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
           if (node.getNodeName()!=null){                  
              nodeMap.put(node.getNodeName(), node.getTextContent());
              list.add(nodeMap);
           }
    }`
```

Comment: Thanks..
I am using XPATH because i need to filter only some information from the XML(i Given only sample) , but in your code how it is possible if suppose[ <name><firstName>...</firstName><lastName>...</lastName></name> ] i mean some element have nested elements, i used recursion for that but not working properly , if any suggestion , please ur Welcome..

Comment: in Your code  if (node.getNodeName()!=null){                  
              nodeMap.put(node.getNodeName(), node.getTextContent());
              list.add(nodeMap);
           } how it is able to put one employee information in one map. i mean both EMPLID and NAME in one Map then for second into another map and i want to create a list of MAP's

Comment: my complete question is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296126/extract-xml-information-to-listmap-using-xpath   pls have a look if possible  Thanks...