# How to convert string xml to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, xml, dictionary

How I can convert all value of element and attributes of xml to Map of string ?
Is there some library which can do this ? I found library xStream but I dont know how to configure it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa

Comment: Also, you might want to view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296126/extract-xml-information-to-listmap-using-xpath as it provides a good example of how to do this.

Comment: nope sorry none of this answers can help me

Comment: @hudi: That's because your question is far too vague.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just wanna this:

```
public static Map<String, String> convertNodesFromXml(String xml) throws Exception {

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(is);
    return createMap(document.getDocumentElement());
}

public static Map<String, String> createMap(Node node) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (currentNode.hasAttributes()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < currentNode.getAttributes().getLength(); j++) {
                Node item = currentNode.getAttributes().item(i);
                map.put(item.getNodeName(), item.getTextContent());
            }
        }
        if (node.getFirstChild() != null && node.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            map.putAll(createMap(currentNode));
        } else if (node.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            map.put(node.getLocalName(), node.getTextContent());
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it works in some way, but don't forget to correct: Node item = currentNode.getAttributes().item(j); (j instead of i). Also it doesn't collect equal tags, as can be seen at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31245219/2914140 (that solution also has bugs).

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library can convert HashMap to xml and vice verse.

```
import com.github.underscore.U;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("name", "chris");
        map.put("island", "faranga");

        System.out.println(U.toXml(map));

        Map<String, Object> newMap = U.fromXmlMap(U.toXml(map));

        System.out.println(newMap.get("name"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse("C://logs//XML.xml");
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node textChild = nodeList.item(i);
        NodeList childNodes = textChild.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
            Node grantChild = childNodes.item(j);
            NodeList grantChildNodes = grantChild.getChildNodes();
            for (int k = 0; k < grantChildNodes.getLength(); k++) {
                if(!StrUtl.isEmptyTrimmed( grantChildNodes.item(k).getTextContent() ) ) {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(grantChildNodes.item(k).getNodeName() , grantChildNodes.item(k).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(map);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```